# Android : Camera issue with 2.3 onwards

Tags: android, android-camera

I have developed camera application using SurfaceView. It captures image and saves to the sdcard. In 2.1 and 2.2 it works fine but in 2.3 onwards it gives problem.

The exact problem in 2.3 is when I open my camera I am able to see preview in portrait mode but when image is saved its in landscape mode.

I dont know why this is happening? The application works fine in 2.1 and 2.2. If I take picture in portrait mode it saves in portrait only.

waiting for replies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem.
Looks like the SDK has some breaking changes.
Try using the [setDisplayOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29), it solved my problem, hopefully, it will help you.

Good luck.